# Why are the "daughters of Jerusalem" always treated as grammatically masculine in Song of Songs?

Tags: hebrew, song-of-songs

> > According to Bible Hub's Interlinear Bible, in
> >
> > - Songs 1:6, "do not look at me"
> > - Songs 2:7 and 3:5, "that you do not wake and that you do not awaken love"
> > - likewise Songs 8:4, "do not wake and do not awaken love"
> > - Songs 5:8, "if you find my beloved"
> >
> > the verb is masculine plural, even though the people being addressed are explicitly the יְרוּשָׁלִָ֑ם בְּנ֣וֹת ("daughters of Jerusalem", with "daughters" being a feminine plural noun).

Other points in Song of Songs where the accompanying people - who may or may not be the same "daughters of Jerusalem" - are treated grammatically as masculine plural are:

- "Eat, friends; drink, and get drunk on, love" (Songs 5:1), where both the noun "friends" and all the verbs are masculine plural.
- "How you would gaze upon the Shulammitess" (Songs 6:13), addressing those who had said "Return, return, O Shulammitess, return, return, that we may gaze upon you", who are presumably representatives of "her noble people" whom she had just mentioned; the verb "you would gaze" is masculine plural.

But despite the "daughters of Jerusalem" having a masculine plural verb, the "daughters of Zion" addressed in Songs 3:11 have a feminine plural verb! ("Go out and look, O daughters of Zion, upon King Solomon...", where both imperatives are feminine plural; the word "daughters" is the same word בְּנ֥וֹת as in "daughters of Jerusalem".) Incidentally, the previous sentence ends by mentioning the "daughters of Jerusalem".

> > Why are the "daughters of Jerusalem" treated as grammatically masculine? Are they all women, or not?
> >
> > Would it be normal in ancient Hebrew for a crowd of women to be treated as grammatically masculine?
> >
> > (And why is the situation different for the "daughters of Zion", who are treated as grammatically feminine?)

---

[I don't know whether the answer to this question might have some overlap with the answer to my question [What are the banner-bearers in Songs 6:4 and 6:10, and why is the word feminine?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/44741/), as that is also about a potentially surprising grammatical gender for a group of people (although in the other direction, namely an army being feminine plural).]

Comment: The Septuaigint's interpretation/translation of this might be helpful as well. [LXX, Songs 1:6](https://en.katabiblon.com/us/index.php?text=LXX&book=Cant&ch=1&interlin=on)

Comment: @elika kohen Thank you. Yes, the LXX is often useful to consider. Did you envisage it providing some particular insight towards my question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks so much for the question. I'd noticed the masc./fem. disparity in other places before, but it was the "daughters of Jerusalem" example that brought up useful hits.

1. [The Gender Challenge of Hebrew](https://books.google.com/books?id=RYvPBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=why%20does%20%22daughters%20of%20Jerusalem%22%20take%20a%20masculine%20verb?&source=bl&ots=G75Oex1Grg&sig=ACfU3U3zMUZoz_I2dWKsnYvY42ek9orDyA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi--K708OznAhWLl3IEHVFZDwwQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=why%20does%20%22daughters%20of%20Jerusalem%22%20take%20a%20masculine%20verb%3F&f=false) - Malka Muchnik - p. 52
2. [The Bible as a Human Witness to Divine Revelation: Hearing the Word of God](https://books.google.com/books?id=tS1ds_kttggC&pg=PA289&lpg=PA289&dq=why%20does%20%22daughters%20of%20Jerusalem%22%20take%20a%20masculine%20verb?&source=bl&ots=ZTCxicsYwm&sig=ACfU3U1SQzPVsJYMc6ANElS2akDVumlbaw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi--K708OznAhWLl3IEHVFZDwwQ6AEwAnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=why%20does%20%22daughters%20of%20Jerusalem%22%20take%20a%20masculine%20verb%3F&f=false) - edited by Randall Heskett, Brian Irwin - p. 289
3. [The Deliberate Substitution of the Masculine for the Feminine Pronominal Suffixes in the Hebrew Bible](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1452210?read-now=1&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) - Mayer G. Slonim [from the Jewish Quarterly Review pp. 139-158]

The third source [and seeming treasure trove of examples] is a JSTOR article. It states on p. 158:

> In conclusion, this survey of the evidence seems to indicate that the
>   scribes deliberately changed the gender of pronominal suffixes to
>   force the reader, through the shock of ungrammatical endings, to
>   ponder some hidden meaning of the text....

He goes on to list other observations; however, the above statement fits best from my angle of study.

4. [Song of Songs - Which is Solomon's](http://www.biblefragrances.com/studies/song1.html) - Ron Wallace

> Incidentally, she uses the 2nd masculine PLURAL form of the verb
>   whenever she addresses the group designated as the daughters of
>   Jerusalem. This normally means that the group addressed is all male or
>   contains both male and female. In this case we do not see a "mixed"
>   company of men and women unless the group contains several eunuchs.
>   This possibility could explain the use of the masculine plural since
>   the eunuchs would be "officially" identified with the daughters of
>   Jerusalem, being ever present and attending them.

Personally, I think it's possible that the *many* 'curiosities' in the Tanach have to do with 'spiritual origins/parents'. Ron Wallace comments that the Shulamite woman appears to have only a mother. Certainly Esau, Benjamin and the 'beautiful, red' David have unique origins.

Ever grateful to those who supply the OT interlinear and vast commentary/studies to allow such as me to participate in this intriguing, marvelous jourey.